TypeScript failed to inference union type correctlly with `if` guard
Does anyone know why the code below has a type error even if there is already a if guard before the code that creates the variant variable?
How could I fix that without writing my own user-defined type guard?
type PersonDetails = {
  gender: 'man' | 'woman',
  height: 'tall' | 'short',
}

export type PersonVariant =
  | {
      gender: 'man',
      height: 'tall',
    }
  | {
      gender: 'woman',
      height: 'tall',
    }
  | {
      gender: 'woman',
      height: 'short',
    };

const details = {} as PersonDetails;

function test() {
    if (details.gender === 'man' && details.height === 'short') {
        return;
    }

    const variant: PersonVariant = {
        gender: details.gender,
        height: details.height,
    };
}

The error message is
Type '{ gender: "man" | "woman"; height: "tall" | "short"; }' is not assignable to type 'PersonVariant'.
  Type '{ gender: "man" | "woman"; height: "tall" | "short"; }' is not assignable to type '{ gender: "woman"; height: "short"; }'.
    Types of property 'gender' are incompatible.
      Type '"man" | "woman"' is not assignable to type '"woman"'.
        Type '"man"' is not assignable to type '"woman"'.


The compound check doesn't seem to discriminate correctly: https://tsplay.dev/WyLAbm But separating the two seems right: https://tsplay.dev/W4gqOm

The issue you're encountering is due to TypeScript's type narrowing mechanism. In your test function, TypeScript cannot automatically infer that after checking details.gender === 'man' && details.height === 'short' is false, the only valid combination left would correspond to a valid PersonVariant.
To resolve this, you need to help TypeScript understand that the details object will conform to one of the valid combinations of PersonVariant. One way to achieve this is by using a type assertion or refining the types with more explicit checks.
Here are a few approaches:
Approach 1: Type Assertion
If you're confident that the remaining combinations are valid PersonVariant, you can use a type assertion:
function test() {
    if (details.gender === 'man' && details.height === 'short') {
        return;
    }

    const variant: PersonVariant = {
        gender: details.gender,
        height: details.height,
    } as PersonVariant; // Type assertion
}

Approach 2: Exhaustive Type Checking
You can perform more explicit type checks to ensure that details matches one of the valid PersonVariant combinations:
function test() {
    if (details.gender === 'man' && details.height === 'short') {
        return;
    }

    let variant: PersonVariant;

    if (details.gender === 'man' && details.height === 'tall') {
        variant = { gender: 'man', height: 'tall' };
    } else if (details.gender === 'woman' && details.height === 'tall') {
        variant = { gender: 'woman', height: 'tall' };
    } else {
        variant = { gender: 'woman', height: 'short' };
    }
}

Approach 3: Type Guard
You can create a type guard to narrow down the type to valid PersonVariant combinations:
function isPersonVariant(details: PersonDetails): details is PersonVariant {
    return (
        (details.gender === 'man' && details.height === 'tall') ||
        (details.gender === 'woman' && (details.height === 'tall' || details.height === 'short'))
    );
}

function test() {
    if (details.gender === 'man' && details.height === 'short') {
        return;
    }

    if (isPersonVariant(details)) {
        const variant: PersonVariant = details;
    }
}

